# Error: failed to register for push notifications (Appcelerator pushwoosh module for android)

Tags: android, titanium, push-notification, appcelerator

I keep getting "Failed to register for push notifications" when using the pushwoosh android appcelerator module. (working great on iOS tho!)

here's my trace

```
[INFO][ActivityManager(   60)] Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/.ComOmgmediagroupAttproamActivity }
[INFO][ActivityManager(   60)] Start proc com.omgmediagroup.attProAm for activity com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/.ComOmgmediagroupAttproamActivity: pid=255 uid=10041 gids={3003, 1015}
[INFO][TiApplication(  255)] (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2660 objects / 309088 bytes in 63ms
[INFO][TiApplication(  255)] (main) [494,494] Titanium 2.1.4 (2012/11/09 12:47 51f2c64)
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2402 objects / 434296 bytes in 64ms
[INFO][TiApplication(  255)] (main) [368,862] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] Trying to load lib /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x44ede650
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] Added shared lib /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x44ede650
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x44ede650, skipping init
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] Trying to load lib /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libkroll-v8.so 0x44ede650
[DEBUG][PushnotificationsModule(  255)] (main) [69,931] inside onAppCreate
[INFO][TiRootActivity(  255)] (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] Added shared lib /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libkroll-v8.so 0x44ede650
[ERROR][TiApplication(  255)] (KrollRuntimeThread) [1615,1615] APP PROXY: ti.modules.titanium.app.AppModule@44f06eb8
[WARN][V8Object(  255)] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] Trying to load lib /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libcom.arellomobie.push.so 0x44ede650
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] Added shared lib /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libcom.arellomobie.push.so 0x44ede650
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libcom.arellomobie.push.so 0x44ede650, skipping init
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] Trying to load lib /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libti.admob.so 0x44ede650
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] Added shared lib /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libti.admob.so 0x44ede650
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/lib/libti.admob.so 0x44ede650, skipping init
[INFO][ActivityManager(   60)] Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.omgmediagroup.attProAm/ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity (has extras) }
[INFO][TiAPI   (  255)] module is => [object Object]
[DEBUG][dalvikvm(  255)] GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4127 objects / 477808 bytes in 68ms
[WARN][System.err(  255)] java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receiver for package com.omgmediagroup.attProAm
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(GCMRegistrar.java:143)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at com.arellomobile.android.push.PushManager.onStartup(PushManager.java:102)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at com.arellomobile.android.push.PushManager.onStartup(PushManager.java:87)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at com.arellomobile.push.PushnotificationsModule.pushNotificationsRegister(PushnotificationsModule.java:79)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.nativeRunModule(Native Method)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.doRunModule(V8Runtime.java:146)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.handleMessage(KrollRuntime.java:287)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.handleMessage(V8Runtime.java:172)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
[WARN][System.err(  255)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:109)
[ERROR][TiAPI   (  255)] Error during registration: Failed to register for push notifications
```

Still new at this so I don't quite understand what this log is telling me... obviously there is some kind of conflict with the module and the compiler (i think?)

I've followed the tutorial to a T and can't seem to find any more information on the error.
Is there anyone out there in the wild who has gotten pushwoosh android module for appcelerator to work? Would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassing, but user error within the AndroidManifest.xml file under platforms/android dir.

The instructions (http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/appcelerator-titanium-android-push-notification/) are however somewhat vague - rather than putting the excerpts under the  tag make sure you're putting it within the existing  tag.

EX:

```
<application>
snippet here
</application>
```